# WPF TabControl Proprty Binding with Child Elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol

I have a WPF 4.0 `TabControl` that has three `TabItem`s (aka Children).
Basically each Child has a color, in other words each Tab will have a color.

I want to bind the background of `TabControl` to the currently selected `TabItem`.
So if 
* I select Apples and its background is red, i want the TabControl's background to be Red. 
When 
* I select to Grapes and its background is purple, I want the `TabControl`'s background to be Purple.

I know it has something to do with element binding, but all options I found where specifically towards one specific `TabItem`, and not generic. How can I do this?

Comment: Post some relevant XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TabControl Background="{Binding SelectedItem.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TabItem Background="Red" Header="Red"/>
    <TabItem Background="Green" Header="Green"/>
    <TabItem Background="Blue" Header="Blue"/>
</TabControl>
```